# Meta box Dropdown menu not save in my custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom meta-box for certain custom post type, and one of those fields in the meta-box is a drop down like here! 
Here is my code

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes','mind_scholar_meta_box');
function mind_scholar_meta_box()
{
   add_meta_box('ms_meta_box','Info Meta Box','mind_scholar_meta_fields','team','normal','high');
}
function mind_scholar_meta_fields()
{

   global $post;
   $field=get_post_meta($post->ID,'mind_scholar_key',true);
   $select=get_post_meta($post->ID,'mind_scholar_select_key',true);
   ?>
   <html>
   <body>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td weidth="50%">
            School Name:
         </td>
         <td weidth="50%">
            <input type="text" name="first" value="<?php echo $field ?>">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td width="50%">
            Stars Rating:
         </td>
         <td>
            <select>
               <option value="star_1" <?php selected( $select, 'star_1' ); ?>>Star 1</option>
               <option value="star_2" <?php selected( $select, 'star_2' ); ?>>Star 2</option>
               <option value="star_3" <?php selected( $select, 'star_3' ); ?>>Star 3</option>
               <option value="star_4" <?php selected( $select, 'star_4' ); ?>>Star 4</option>
               <option value="star_5" <?php selected( $select, 'star_5' ); ?>>Star 5</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   </body>
   </html>
   <?php
}
add_action('save_post','save_posts');
function save_posts()
{
   global $post;
   $ms_field=$_POST['first'];
   $ms_field_select=$_POST[''];

   update_post_meta($post->ID,'mind_scholar_key',$ms_field);
   update_post_meta($post->ID,'mind_scholar_select_key',$ms_field_select);

}
```

Unfortunately my drop-down is not saved in my CPT! Can anyone help? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Copy this code and use

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes','mind_scholar_meta_box'); function mind_scholar_meta_box() {    add_meta_box('ms_meta_box','Info Meta Box','mind_scholar_meta_fields','team','normal','high'); } function mind_scholar_meta_fields() {

   global $post;    $field=get_post_meta($post->ID,'mind_scholar_key',true);    $select=get_post_meta($post->ID,'mind_scholar_select_key',true);    ?> <html>    <body>    <table>
      <tr>
         <td weidth="50%">
            School Name:
         </td>
         <td weidth="50%">
            <input type="text" name="first" value="<?php echo $field ?>">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td width="50%">
            Stars Rating:
         </td>
         <td>
            <select name='second_select'>
               <option value="star_1" <?php selected( $select, 'star_1' ); ?>>Star 1</option>
               <option value="star_2" <?php selected( $select, 'star_2' ); ?>>Star 2</option>
               <option value="star_3" <?php selected( $select, 'star_3' ); ?>>Star 3</option>
               <option value="star_4" <?php selected( $select, 'star_4' ); ?>>Star 4</option>
               <option value="star_5" <?php selected( $select, 'star_5' ); ?>>Star 5</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>    </table>    </body>    </html>    <?php } add_action('save_post','save_posts'); function save_posts() {    global $post;    $ms_field=$_POST['first'];    $ms_field_select=$_POST['second_select'];

   update_post_meta($post->ID,'mind_scholar_key',$ms_field);    update_post_meta($post->ID,'mind_scholar_select_key',$ms_field_select);

}
```

Comment: Welcome @Talha ;)

Answer (score 1):

You totally forgot to put a `name` value to the select and to the `$post`

In the metabox render:

```
<select name="ratings">
```

In the `save_posts()` function

```
$ms_field_select = $_POST['ratings'];
```